# Obtener coordenada z en QGIS 3.28

Tags: pyqgis

Como obtener coordenada z de <qgsgeometry: pointz (-463.5 620 20)> en QGIS 3.28

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.